# Jmeter:How to perform load testing on Oracle WebCenter Portal Application?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, oracle-adf, oracleportal

How can I perform Load testing on Oracle Portal Application Using Jmeter?
I recorded the activity using jmeter proxy and run the recorded request but I got unrealistic results.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle portal is nothing but an ADF application, so it can be testes as any other ADF application.

You basically need an approach as Pino uses here:

http://soadev.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/jmeter-load-test-oracle-adf-applications.html

Registering tests with JMeter is a tricky business, you need to validate your scenario once recorded by running it with only one thread and check the server logs (in case you use your custom logger) to make sure the functionality on the server is being executed.